# Standard Rest API - Logs

Tags: rest-api, debug-logs

In my organization I am doing a simple standard Rest API Call to insert Account:

```
 URL : https://MyInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Account

 Body : {   
            "Name" : "Salesforce",
            "BillingStreet" : "Landmark @ 1 Market Street",
            "BillingCity" : "San Francisco",
            "BillingState" : "California",
            "Industry" : "Technology"
        }
```

Is there a way to Get/Save the log of this CallIn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using Event Log Monitoring feature, Salesforce will log every API invocation and these can be queried or exported to third party logging tools like Splunk or SumoLogic

However, the log won't contain the POST body. It will contain

- The time/date
- The endpoint invoked `https://MyInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Account`
- The REST method (e.g. `POST`)
- The source IP address
- The running user
- The elapsed and CPU time
- Other details as documented for the [REST API Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_restapi.htm)

Comment: Thanks, Can you please add an example ?
With this query, I don't get any records : [ SELECT  id , EventType FROM EventLogFile ]  
I create Accounts using Rest API through Postman every Days. Do I need any specific configuration ?

Comment: Did you license Shield Event Monitoring?   See the Trailhead on Event Monitoring

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to Get/Save the log of this API call in the same application/tool(ways may differ for tool like POSTMAN or Workbench).

However, you can enable the debug log for the user that the application using steps as Setup-> Logs -> Debug Logs.

You can look for more logging with help of below documentation:

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_debugging_debug_log.htm